# Javascript- passing through this loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, indexof

I am making a Hangman game. I am using the indexOf() Function to check if a letter is in a word. Each letter has a button and when the button is clicked the following happens (this function is for the letter A):

```
function A(event) {

  if (event.target.classList.contains("disabled")) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  document.getElementById("A").style.opacity = "0.5";
  event.target.classList.add("disabled");
  score = score + 1;
  document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = score;

  for (var letter = 0; letter <= randomWord.length; letter++) {
    if (randomWord[letter].indexOf("a") !== -1) {
      document.getElementById("letter_" + letter).innerHTML = "A";
    } else {
      mistakesLeft = mistakesLeft - 1;
      document.getElementById("attempsLeft").innerHTML = mistakesLeft;
      console.log(mistakesLeft);

      if (mistakesLeft == 7) {
        document.getElementById("part-1").style.display = "block";
      } else if (mistakesLeft == 6) {
        document.getElementById("part-2").style.display = "block";
      } else if (mistakesLeft == 5) {
        document.getElementById("part-3").style.display = "block";
      } else if (mistakesLeft == 4) {
        document.getElementById("part-4").style.display = "block";
      } else if (mistakesLeft == 3) {
        document.getElementById("part-5").style.display = "block";
      } else if (mistakesLeft == 2) {
        document.getElementById("part-6").style.display = "block";
      } else if (mistakesLeft == 1) {
        document.getElementById("part-7").style.display = "block";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("part-8").style.display = "block";
      }
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

For some reason when my random word has "A" in it and it is not the first letter it doesn't print out into `document.getElementById("letter_" + letter).innerHTML = "A";`, instead it continues into the else statement and thinks that there isn't an "A" in the word. If the "A" is the first letter of the word it does what it is meant to do. I noticed that the problem could be the break at the bottom of the code (It can't get to the next letter because of the break)- How could I fix it so the loop continues past the first loop until it reaches the length of the word without subtracting any part of the mistakesLeft?

Comment: Shouldn't that if condition must be .indexOf("A")

Comment: Does the `randomWord` hold the  word you need to search?

Comment: no, the randomwords are all lowercase and yes the randomWord holds the string of a word you need to guess.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
for (var letter = 0; letter <= randomWord.length - 1; letter++) {
    if (randomWord[letter] === 'a') {
      ...
```

You don't have to go through the word and use `indexOf` at the same time. The function indexOf searches for a letter for you. Also note `randomWord.length - 1`.

Out of the scope of this question, I don't think you need to have a separate function for all the letters. Create a general purpose function and call it at every button click while passing the corresponding letter to it as an argument.

Comment: A more idiomatic fix for the fencepost error would be to use `<` instead of `<=`

Comment: Unfortunately that still dosen't work and has the same effect as what I said at the top. The loop only prints the first letter of the word and when it goes through the if statement it also goes through the else statement

Comment: Create a fiddle, isolate the code that generates the error and give us the link. The problem is not in the loop. It is elsewhere.

Comment: Ok, I have created a fiddle, here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/svhfogbf/. I may need to put in all of the code so tell me if you need all of it. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: It says *A is not a function* when I click on the letter "A". And your array had about 1000 elements in the fiddle. Please include only the minimum code related to this error and please make sure it works up to the point we discuss here.

Comment: Ok, I have fixed as much as I can. The function A is still not working but I have decreased code and get startGame() to work which may do the trick. I may try creating a link to it instead of using a fiddle.

Comment: Your fiddle works perfectly when I delete that array and set the `randWord = "this is a test";` it identifies the char 'a' anywhere.

Comment: DOn't worry I fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to alter the logic for all your handlers here's a somewhat tidied up version

```
function letterClicked(event) {
  var elem = event.target,
      ch = elem.id,
      reg = new RegEx(ch),
      found = false;

  if (elem.classList.contains("disabled")) {
    return false; //you want to return early in this case
  }

  elem.style.opacity = "0.5";
  elem.classList.add("disabled");
  score = score + 1;
  document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = score;

  if(!(match = reg.exec(randomWord)) {
     mistakes++;
     document.getElementById("part-" + mistakes).style.display = "block";
  } else {
    do {
      document.getElementById("letter_" + match.index).innerHTML = ch;
    }while (match = reg.exec(randomWord));
  }
}
```

Comment: @DisplayName you think that's complicated? it works for all letters not just one at a time and in way fewer lines. If you used jquery it could be even simpler